# ASP.NET Core ajax, JSON object returns property IEnumerable with value null

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax

Here is the JS and the ViewModel, everything looks fine but the IEnumerable inside the object doesn't load. In the Controller order.OrderItems isn't null but in the response it is.

```
0: {id: 2, orderItems: null, destination: "a", status: "sent"}
```

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/api/Driver",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.table > tr').slice(0).remove();
                    $.each(data, function (i, order) {
                        var button = "<button class='accordion'>" + "OrderId: " + order.id + ", Destination: " + order.destination + "</button>" + "<div class='driverPanel'>";
                        $('.table').append(button);
                        $.each(order.orderItems, function (j, orderItem) {
                            var row =
                                "<p>" + orderItem.product.name + ", Amount: " + orderItem.amount + "<p>";

                        $('.table').append(row);
                        })
                        var btnDone = '<button onclick="markAsDone(' + order.id + ')" class="btn btn-success">Mark As Done</button>'
                        $('.table').append(btnDone);
                        $('.table').append("</div>");


                    });

                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert(data.responseText);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data.responseText);
                }
            });
```

```
    public class OrderDriverViewModel : IMapFrom<Order>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<OrderItemOutputModel> OrderItems { get; set; }

        public string Destination{ get; set; }

        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Looks to be an issue with serialization of IEnumerable, before I speculate on a possible cause, is it possible for you to convert OrderItems to a List object on the server, then serialize the results?

Comment: That fixed the problem, but I don't know why.